# $(1+x)^a$ McLaurin series

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, power-series

My book has a small section about the Maclaurin series of $f(x) = (1+x)^a$.
We look at this function only when $x \gt -1$. So the domain is just $(-1, \infty)$

The number $a$ is a real constant (could be any number).

Now... We would like to know for which values of $x$ and $a$ it is true that:

$$(1+x)^a = 1 + \dbinom{a}{1}x +  \dbinom{a}{2}x^2 + \dbinom{a}{3}x^3 + ... \tag{*}$$

(i.e. that this series on the RHS is convergent and its sum is the LHS).

Here we used the generalized binomial coefficient notation:

$$\dbinom{a}{n} = \frac{a(a-1)\dots(a-(n-1))}{n!}$$

- For $-1 \lt x \lt 1$ and $a$ any constant, I was able to follow the proof that the residual term $R_n$ in the Maclaurin series tends to $0$, hence the equality (*) holds true. The proof is quite convoluted but I do understand it well. It uses the Cauchy form of the residual term. So far so good.

But I got confused with the boundary cases.

- If $a=1$ and for any $x \gt -1$ my book says the equality is also true. That part I think I can understand too. Because in that case, all terms in the series after the second term are zeros. So the series is in fact a finite sum and is obviously $(1+x)$.
- For $x=1$ my book requires $a\ge 1$ for the series to be convergent... But I don't really see why. When I looked at the things proved already in the proof, I think they all hold true for any $a$ (when $x=1$). So if $x=1$ isn't it true for any $a$ that the series is convergent and its sum is $2^a$ ?
- Also, for the other cases (except these 3 cases above) e.g. when $x>1$, my book doesn't prove that the series is divergent. Is that too complicated for a first real analysis course? I guess that's why they skipped that part. But that's just my guess, I could be wrong.

Comment: Which analysis book are you referencing?

Comment: It's not in English, you wouldn't know it, I guess. I think it doesn't really matter.

Comment: The series  is the Generalized Binomial Theorem, discovered by Isaac Newton. If $|x|<1$ the series converges to $(1+x)^a$ for any $a$.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet This is not true that it converges for any a.

Comment: @peter.petrov, why?

Comment: @Invisible I didn't see the part where he says when $|x| < 1$. For such $x$, yes that is true, and I said I understand the proof for that. That wasn't my question though. See the answer provided.

Comment: I know it wasn't your Q, which concerns convergence when $|x|\ge 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second question ($x=1$), take for example $a=-1$. The sum is then
$$
\left.(1+x)^{-1}\right|_{x=1} = \left.1 + \binom{-1}{1}x+\binom{-1}{2}x^2+\binom{-1}{3}x^3+\dots\right|_{x=1} = 1-1+1-1+\dots
$$
which clearly does not converge to $\frac{1}{2}$.

If $x>1$ the series diverges for any noninteger $a$. For positive integer $a$ it actually converges for any $x$ because, as you noticed, there is a finite number of nonzero terms.

Comment: Thank you. This seems right. I will reread and rethink it one more time.

Comment: Btw, how do we prove that when $x \gt 1$ it diverges for for any non-integer a? I think I have an idea (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_tests#Raabe%E2%80%93Duhamel's_test) but just want to see what your approach is. In that same case (for $x > 1$), does it also diverge for negative integers $a$? I think it does, right? If you have a good text about that function $(1+x)^a$ and its Maclaurin series (which looks at all possible cases for $a$ and $x$), can you point me? Russian is also OK, I can read in Russian.

Comment: Why does $\alpha\in\Bbb Z^-$ matter? If $\alpha\not\in\Bbb N_0$ I think you can use [D'Alembert criterion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test) because there won't be any division by $0$:

$$\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=\frac{\binom{\alpha}{n+1}|x|^{n+1}}{\binom{\alpha}n|x|^n}=\frac{|\alpha-n|}{n+1}|x|\overset{n\to+\infty}{\to}|x|,$$ so the series absolutely converges for $|x|<1$ and diverges for $|x|>1$.

Comment: Furthermore, if one defines $f(x)=(1+x)^\alpha$ and $g(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{\alpha}n|x|^n,x\in(-1,1)$ it can be proven that both $f$ and $g$ are the solutions to the differential equation $(1+x)y'=\alpha y,y(0)=1$. Since the solution is unique, $f=g$ on $(-1,1).$

Comment: You can also use the following result:


Let $I\subseteq\Bbb R$ be an open interval, $c\in I$ and $f\in C^\infty(I).$ If there exist $n_0\in\Bbb N,\delta>0, M>0, C>0$ s. t. $|f^{(n)}(x)|\le CM^nn!,\forall x\in I'=(c-\delta,c+\delta)\cap I \forall n\ge n_0,$ then the Taylor series of $f$ around $c$ converges to $f(x),\forall x\in I'\cap\left(c-\frac1M,c+\frac1M\right).$

Comment: Then, if you take $n_0>\alpha+1, C=\left|\binom{\alpha}{n_0-1}\right|\max\left\{\left(\frac32\right)^\alpha,\left(\frac12\right)^\alpha\right\},M=2$ you can prove a weaker result that $f=g,\forall x\in\left(-\frac12,\frac12\right).$

Comment: @peter.petrov, if you can read Serbo-Croatian, the proof of all this is in a book by Svetozar Kurepa (_Matematička analiza_ $I,II,III$) and in the script by Boris Guljaš we used in the first year.

Comment: @peter.petrov. If $|x|>1$ and if $a\not\in \Bbb N_0$ then none of the terms in the series is $0$ and the ratio of the $(n+1)$st term to the $n$th term tends to $x$ so  the absolute values of the $terms$ tends to $\infty$.

Comment: Thank you all, guys. I have now plenty of good notes to read and think through. Thanks!